# Changing returned content type in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a zip file with a custom extension that needs to be returned as content type application/zip, but for some reason, no matter what I do, it always gets returned as text/html.

It would seem that configuring a content negotiation manager as in this article https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work for me. If I request a .zip file through the same controller/method it works perfectly.

I've tried configuring several different properties in an attempt to accomplish my goal, but here's my latest from my application-context.xml.

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/zip" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xyz" value="application/zip" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here are my headers from my browser:

```
Remote Address:::1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/app/faces/download/148943e4ead.xyz
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=gcvvicbqtlyyrbgnth3qurfy; jwplayer.volume=100; SESSION-GUID=f8vdloov22qbmx6r; plushContainerWidth=100%25; plushMultiOps=1; plushNoTopMenu=0; SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2; _ga=GA1.1.1642769916.1411099193
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8080
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36

Response Headers

Content-Length:2585515
Content-Type:text/html
Server:Jetty(6.1.26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was overcomplicating the issue. I only needed this functionality on one controller method, so simply adding `produces = "application/zip"` to my RequestMapping worked just fine.

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/download/{fileName:.+}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/zip")
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource download(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
...
}
```